# A persistent FIFO queue implementation on PHP

Tags: php, fifo

I need a FIFO queue implementation on PHP. I know that it's not so difficult but the problem is that, this queue must be stored on somewhere else such as memcache. I'll process this queue by cron jobs.

I found MemcacheQ, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use [MEMQ](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/memq) that is a simple php class that implements a queue using memcache as data store.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fifo queue with max length

```
function fifoQueueArr($arr, $item, $length = 10){
  array_push($arr, $item);
  if(count($arr) < $length){
    return $arr;
  }
  return array_slice($arr, (count($arr)-$length), $length);
}
```